# how to initialize Angularjs ng-model in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, erb

A question about using angularjs two way binding and in rails erb files.

Suppose value of input in my .erb file has an original value i.e.

example.erb

```
<input type="text" value=" <%= @item.title %> " ng-model ="item.title">
```

As you may notice in above example, the input is also binded with a angularJs model. 
example.js

```
mayApp.controller('newItemController', function itemController($scope) { 
   $scope.item = {title:"angularJs model value", price: 1000}
}
```

I found that the original @item.title is overridden by the angularJs model value.
However, I want things happen in the opposite way, that is, the angular js model is initialised by value from .erb file. How can I do that?

I have tried to put example.js into asset pipeline. i.e. 
example.js.erb

```
mayApp.controller('newItemController', function itemController($scope) { 
   $scope.item = {title:"<%= @item.title %>", price: 1000}
}
```

but the @item is alway nil in the pipeline. I suppose the @item is only available in views?

Comment: AngularJS knows nothing and cares not about your rails model. Also, rails assets are not in scope of your rails model/controller so no wonder @item.title is undefined in example.js.erb.

Comment: @Stewie I agree with you. I know why this happened. Do you have any suggestions about how to initialise  Angular model with  value of rails models.

Comment: As a quick solution you might try to embed your example.js <script> into example.erb view partial. That way `<%= @item.title %>` will/should be interpolated with your `item` model while generating the html.

Comment: This is actually a very sensible question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ng-init` for this:

```
<input type="text" ng-init="item.title = '<%= @item.title %>'" ng-model ="item.title">
```

Comment: ok, updated. maybe ng-value will only work with other input types.